# parsing hashtag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a code like this and i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined" in console, im not so good at javascript

```
<script>
    parse_tag = function (str) {
        var create_link = function (url, text) {
            var link = $("<a>", {
                text: text,
                href: url,
                target: "_blank"
            });

            return link.prop('outerHTML');
        };

        // parse username
        str = str.replace(/[@]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+/g, function (s) {
            return create_link("http://twitter.com/" + s.replace('@', ''), s);
        });

        // parse hashtags
        str = str.replace(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+/g, function (s) {
            return create_link("http://search.twitter.com/search?q=" + s.replace('#', ''), s);
        });

        return str;
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var text = $('.desc');
        parse_tag(text);    
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have a great smile! So what ?

Comment: `text` is a jQuery object, and you want a string, so `parse_tag(text.text());` or something. And then you should actually do something with the result. But that doesn’t explain the error you asked about, so could you at least try debugging a little more to see why it’s `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function like

```
var text = $('.desc');
parse_tag(text);
```

And the function is

```
parse_tag = function (str) { // <-- str suppose to be a string

    var create_link = function(url, text){
        // ...
        return link.prop('outerHTML');
    }

    //...
    str = str.replace(/[@]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+/g, function (s) {
        return create_link("http://twitter.com/" + s.replace('@', ''), s);
    });
}
```

In this case, `str` should be string but according to `var text = $('.desc');` it's a `jQuery` object so you can change either `var text = $('.desc');` to `var text = $('.desc').text();` or make changes in your `parse_tag` function, otherwise, you'll get error something like `object doesn't support this property or method`.

Also, you are using two `regex` as `/[@]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+/g,` and `/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+/g` but both are being used on a link, something like

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/me" target="_blank">@me</a>`
```

Because you are returning an `a` tag using

```
return link.prop('outerHTML');
```

So, make changes in your `regex` too or maybe it's better to use the replace on `link`'s `text/href`, so make sure you make the changes.